# PHP save information in HTML then download it

Tags: php, html

I'm working on a task where a website is bound using PHP and the function of the PHP is to edit the HTML file in the server then download it to the user.

I've tried PHP DOM and no luck.

So far here's the PHP code

```
<a href="download.php?filename=ProjectA.html" class="links">Download ProjectA</a></td>  </tr>  <tr>    <td align="left" valign="middle"><img src="files/tick.jpg" width="16" height="16" /></td>    <td align="left" valign="middle">
```

and the HTML code I want to edit is the following line 137

```
<form accept-charset="utf-8" action="Enter your ID"
    method="post">
```

My download.php:

```
<?php

function output_file($file, $name, $mime_type='')
{
 /*
 This function takes a path to a file to output ($file),  the filename that the browser will see ($name) and  the MIME type of the file ($mime_type, optional).
 */

 //Check the file premission
 if(!is_readable($file)) die('File not found or inaccessible!');

 $size = filesize($file);
 $name = rawurldecode($name);

 /* Figure out the MIME type | Check in array */
 $known_mime_types=array(
    "pdf" => "application/pdf",
    "txt" => "text/plain",
    "html" => "text/html",
    "htm" => "text/html",
    "exe" => "application/octet-stream",
    "zip" => "application/zip",
    "doc" => "application/msword",
    "xls" => "application/vnd.ms-excel",
    "ppt" => "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint",
    "gif" => "image/gif",
    "png" => "image/png",
    "jpeg"=> "image/jpg",
    "jpg" =>  "image/jpg",
    "php" => "text/plain"
 );

 if($mime_type==''){
     $file_extension = strtolower(substr(strrchr($file,"."),1));
     if(array_key_exists($file_extension, $known_mime_types)){
        $mime_type=$known_mime_types[$file_extension];
     } else {
        $mime_type="application/force-download";
     };
 };

 //turn off output buffering to decrease cpu usage
 @ob_end_clean(); 

 // required for IE, otherwise Content-Disposition may be ignored
 if(ini_get('zlib.output_compression'))
  ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off');

 header('Content-Type: ' . $mime_type);
 header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$name.'"');
 header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
 header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');

 /* The three lines below basically make the 
    download non-cacheable */
 header("Cache-control: private");
 header('Pragma: private');
 header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");

 // multipart-download and download resuming support
 if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']))
 {
    list($a, $range) = explode("=",$_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'],2);
    list($range) = explode(",",$range,2);
    list($range, $range_end) = explode("-", $range);
    $range=intval($range);
    if(!$range_end) {
        $range_end=$size-1;
    } else {
        $range_end=intval($range_end);
    }

    $new_length = $range_end-$range+1;
    header("HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content");
    header("Content-Length: $new_length");
    header("Content-Range: bytes $range-$range_end/$size");
 } else {
    $new_length=$size;
    header("Content-Length: ".$size);
 }

 /* Will output the file itself */
 $chunksize = 1*(1024*1024); //you may want to change this
 $bytes_send = 0;
 if ($file = fopen($file, 'r'))
 {
    if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']))
    fseek($file, $range);

    while(!feof($file) && 
        (!connection_aborted()) && 
        ($bytes_send<$new_length)
          )
    {
        $buffer = fread($file, $chunksize);
        print($buffer); //echo($buffer); // can also possible
        flush();
        $bytes_send += strlen($buffer);
    }
 fclose($file);
 } else
 //If no permissiion
 die('Error - can not open file.');
 //die
die();
}
//Set the time out
set_time_limit(0);

//path to the file
$file_path='files/'.$_REQUEST['filename'];


//Call the download function with file path,file name and file type
output_file($file_path, ''.$_REQUEST['filename'].'', 'text/plain');


?>
```

I need assist on this :(

Comment: There is no php code there...

Comment: What you have in your download.php file?

Comment: [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) / [`file_put_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)

Comment: @Darren , can you edit specific line in a HTML with it??

Comment: @user3671699 You can get the contents, put them in a `<textarea>` Allow user to edit them and the `file_put_contents()` it back into the file.

Comment: @darren, could you show an example so i can give you an answer +1 for helping me out @.@

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use something like `file_get_contents()` to fetch the data from the file.

*The below is pseudo code as I do not know your directory/file structure.*

First you'll need to fetch the file contents:

```
<?php 

$file = 'path/to/file';
// check if file exists
if(!file_exists($)) {
    die("File: {$file} does not exist");
} else {
    $data = file_get_contents($file);
}

?>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<!-- form stuff here -->
<textarea name="content" cols="10"><?php echo (isset($data))? $data : '';?></textarea>
<!-- more form stuff here -->
</bod>
</html>
```

Now when they submit the data, you'll just use `file_put_contents()`.

```
<?php 

$file = 'path/to/file';

$data = $_POST['content'];
// test if content put successfully
if(!file_put_contents($file, $data)) {
    echo 'failed';
} else {
    echo 'success';
}

?>
```

Comment: Erh, but the PHP and HTML is a different file not in the same file.

Comment: The user put something in the PHP form then it will transfer to another file in the server , save it then download it using header function